# One IP, One Port, Multiple Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualhost, nat

I am looking for a solution to forward one public IP address and one specific port to different machines based on hostname (as of now, I need it only for HTTP).

The current setup is NAT on a commodity router (it only provide simple public port to private IP address / port forwarding). I can add a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine before the router if required, but prefer not to do so.

So ideally, I would like to have the current setup and the forwarding is done on one of the Windows Servers. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want is really name based virtual hosts.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Comment: Yes! Except that I need to forward to different servers not just one.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Apache's name based virtual hosts and mod_proxy to redirect it to another host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      www.example.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.254.197/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.254.197/

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      www.other_example.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.254.198/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.254.198/

</VirtualHost>
```

The above will catch the example.com and other_example.com on your front facing IP address and then pass each of them off to a different IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy very expensive devices from Cisco, f5 and others which do this, or more simply you could setup an instance of [squid cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/Download/) to listen for incoming requests and then either rewrite the URL on squid or maintain local name/address mappings in your hosts file.

If you need to handle HTTPS, then run an instance of [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/download/binaries.html) in front of the HTTP proxy to terminate the SSL.

Comment: BTW: you can run a custom Linux installation on a lot of commodity routers (and hence run stunnel and squid on the router). See also http://openwrt.org/